# How to concatenate strings without partial duplication in PHP?

Tags: php, merge, substring, string-concatenation

I have a series of strings in **PHP array**.

Each string sometimes overlaps with the previous one (by one or more words) and sometimes doesn't overlap:

```
$My_Array = [

  'The quick',
  'quick brown',
  'quick brown fox',
  'jumps over the',
  'over the',
  'lazy dog',
];
```

I'd like to merge only those strings which have *overlaps*.

**ie.** where the characters at the *start* of one string already exist at the *end* of the preceding string.

My aim is to return the following array:

```
$My_Processed_Array = [

  'The quick brown fox',
  'jumps over the',
  'lazy dog',
];
```

---

**Work Completed so far:**

I have put this together, which works in *this instance*, but I'm sceptical that it will cover all cases:

```
function process_my_array($array) {
    
  for ($i = (count($array) - 1); $i > 0; $i--) {
  
    // TURN STRING ELEMENTS INTO MINI-ARRAYS
    $Current_Element = explode(' ', trim($array[$i]));
    $Previous_Element = explode(' ', trim($array[($i - 1)]));
    
    $End_Loop = FALSE;
    
    // STRING-MATCHING ROUTINE
    while ($End_Loop === FALSE) {

      if ($Current_Element[0] === $Previous_Element[(count($Previous_Element) - 1)]) {            
        array_shift($Current_Element);
        $array[$i] = implode(' ', $Current_Element);
        $array[($i - 1)] .= ' '.$array[$i];
        unset($array[$i]);
        $array = array_values($array);
        
        $End_Loop = TRUE;
      }
        
      elseif (count($Current_Element) > 1) {
        $Current_Element[0] .= ' '.$Current_Element[1];
        unset($Current_Element[1]);
        $Current_Element = array_values($Current_Element);
      
        if (isset($Previous_Element[(count($Previous_Element) - 2)])) {
          $Previous_Element[(count($Previous_Element) - 2)] .= ' '.$Previous_Element[(count($Previous_Element) - 1)];
          unset($Previous_Element[(count($Previous_Element) - 1)]);
          $Previous_Element = array_values($Previous_Element);
        }
      }
      
      elseif (count($Current_Element) === 1) {
        $End_Loop = TRUE;
      }
    }
  }
    
  return $array;
}
```

More importantly, I'm almost certain there must be **a much simpler way** to achieve the target outcome than what I've put together above.

Comment: I hope my snippet was correct and good to read?

Comment: Hi @nice_dev and thanks very much for your contribution! I'm asking the question above because I'm guessing there must be a much simpler way to achieve the target outcome.

Comment: Mine is not readable?

Comment: Yes, it's readable, @nice_dev. I just wasn't clear what the differences were between your approach and my approach.

Comment: I guess there are no inbuilt array functions do this.

Comment: I spent some more time hunting around, but I conclude you're absolutely right. Many thanks for your help, @nice_dev.

Comment: Glad I could help and my solution is useful and readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Split each string by space using `explode()`.
- Compare it with previous exploded string one by one.
- Create a new pointer for comparison.
- If the current pointer of current word doesn't match with current word in `prev`, reset pointer to 0. Else, keep incrementing current pointer.
- This way, we got a hang of longest suffix in the previous string that is a prefix in the current string.
- Slice out the exploded array from current pointer.
- To stitch the residue of current string with the previous one, use `array_merge` and `implode` them back in the end.
- If the current pointer happens to be `0` even after comparison, you can safely assume it is a completely new word.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$My_Processed_Array = [];

$prev = [];
$curr = [];
foreach($My_Array as $val){
    $val = explode(" ",$val);
    $ptr = 0;
    foreach($prev as $index => $prev_val){
        if($prev_val == $val[$ptr]){
            $ptr++;
        }else{
            $ptr = 0;
        }
        if($ptr == count($val)){
            if($index == count($prev) - 1) break;
            $ptr = 0;
        }
    }    
    $sliced_data = array_slice($val, $ptr);
    if($ptr == 0 && !empty($curr)){
        $My_Processed_Array[] = implode(" " ,$curr);
        $curr = [];
    }
    $curr = array_merge($curr,$sliced_data);
    $prev = $val;
}

if(!empty($curr)){
    $My_Processed_Array[] = implode(" " ,$curr);
}
```